# Getting data from Telrik RadGridView into List

Tags: wpf, excel, mvvm, telerik

Im having a RadGrid... on making an filtering or sorting in the view(UI), I want to export the Data from the grid into excel.(MVVM PATTERN)

I;ve checked for the Excel code, its working, i.e i m able to save the data from the list into the excel file. But its saving the old/initial data from the list, not the data in View/UI which is sorted or filtered.

When making an Click for export, i want to get the current data(sorted or filltered) from the RadGridView into and new list.

Please help !! ..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the MVVM tag to your question, but you don't seem to be using (or possibly understanding) MVVM if you are asking the question that you are asking. In WPF in general, but particularly when using MVVM, we have the data that is displayed in the UI in our view models. Therefore, if you had correctly been using MVVM, then you would have done something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" />
```

If you have been sorting and filtering the data from your view model (in response to user actions), then to save the filtered, sorted data, you could just do something like this:

```
DataProvider.Save(YourItems);
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE REPLY SIR.. U R RIGHT BT AS M NEW...IM WORKING ON TELERIK RADGRID VIEW... SO PLZ CAN U CONVERT IT II THE FORM OF TELERIK